# Update column value for group of rows whose values are same

Tags: php, mysql

Want to update group(any unique str) for a combination of common values of company_id and city_id columns.

Table Data

```
    ----------------------------------------
    | id |   group  | company_id | city_id |
    ----------------------------------------
    | 1  |  (null)  |   1        |    12   |
    | 2  |  (null)  |   1        |    12   |
    | 3  |  (null)  |   1        |    13   |
    | 4  |  (null)  |   1        |    13   |
    | 5  |  (null)  |   2        |    12   |
    | 6  |  (null)  |   2        |    12   |
    | 7  |  (null)  |   3        |    14   |
    ----------------------------------------
```

Expected result

```
----------------------------------------
| id |   group  | company_id | city_id |
----------------------------------------
| 1  |   123    |   1        |    12   |
| 2  |   123    |   1        |    12   |
| 3  |   223    |   1        |    13   |
| 4  |   223    |   1        |    13   |
| 5  |   345    |   2        |    12   |
| 6  |   345    |   2        |    12   |
| 7  |   467    |   3        |    14   |
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: What will be the basis for the value of `group`?

Comment: Group column values can be any unique value for particular group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CAST` with `CONCAT`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE table
SET group = CAST(CONCAT(company_id, city_id) AS INTEGER)
WHERE group IS NULL;
```

If `group` column is of type `varchar` only then you don't need to use `CAST`, e.g.:

```
UPDATE table
SET group = CONCAT(company_id, city_id)
WHERE group IS NULL;
```

This will make sure the value of `group` is unique for any combination of `company_id` and `city_id`.

Here's the documentation for [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) and [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat).